Differentiation of the constraint of the generalized eigenvalues problem optimization
I'm currently reading Element of Dimensionality Reduction and Manifold Learning from B. Ghojogh, M. Crowley, F. Karray and A. Ghodsi.
My knowledge on calculus is a bit rusted which is why I make sure I understand every equation development I read in the book. Reading on the optimization of the generalized eigen value problem (eq. 2.59) I stubble upon some difficulties on differentiating the constraint.
The problem is stated as the following
$$
\begin{matrix}
  \text{maximize}_\Phi & Tr(\Phi^T A \Phi) \\
  \text{subject to} & \Phi^TB\Phi=I
\end{matrix}
$$
With $A$ and $B$ symmetric matrices, $\Phi=[\phi_0, ..., \phi_n]$ the matrix filed with the eigenvectors and $\Lambda$ a diagonal matrix filled with eigenvalues $\Lambda_{i,i} = \lambda_i$.
Which gives the following Lagragian:
$$\mathcal{L} = Tr(\Phi^TA\Phi) - Tr(\Lambda^T(\Phi^TB\Phi-I))$$
$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\Phi}=0$$
I can differentiate the first part of the lagrangian without much issues:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\Phi}Tr(\Phi^TA\Phi) = A^T\Phi + A\Phi = 2A\Phi$$
But I can't figure out how is the result of the second part of the lagragian obtained:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\Phi}Tr(\Lambda^T(\Phi^TB\Phi-I))$$
I just know from the book that the result is :
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\Phi}Tr(\Lambda^T(\Phi^TB\Phi-I)) = 2B\Phi\Lambda$$
Could someone help me figure this out ?
Thank you very much !

$
\def\L{\Lambda}  \def\P{\Phi}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\red{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Use a colon to denote the $\sf Frobenius\ Product$,
which has the following properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
B:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\sf Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{XY}:B &= X:\LR{BY^T} \;=\; Y:\LR{X^TB} \\
}$$
This product makes it fairly simple to calculate the desired gradient
$$\eqalign{
f
 &= \trace{\L^T\P^TB\,\P\,-\,\L^TI} \\
 &= \P\L:B\,\P \;-\; \L:I \\
df &= \c{d\P}\:\L:B\,\P \;+\; \P\L:B\;\c{d\P} \;-\; \c{0} \\
 &= d\P:B\,\P\L^T \;+\; B^T\P\L:d\P \\
 &= \LR{B\,\P\L^T + B^T\P\L} : d\P \\
\grad{f}{\P}
 &=  {B\,\P\L^T + B^T\P\L} \\
}$$
But in the current problem, we know that $B\;{\rm and}\;\L\,$
are symmetric, therefore
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f}{\P}
 &=  2\,B\,\P\L \qq\qq\qq\qq\qq
}$$

Really clever ! Thank you very much sir !
